# linux-tomcat - add command to startup.sh

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat

How can I add a command at the end of the tomcat `startup.sh` script to execute a file.

I think it is something like this. Assuming my file needs start as command passed to it below:

```
exec "/path/to/file/file" start
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to accomplish?  You probbably don't want to edit a script which was installed by the system, but you might want to create a wrapper.  Assuming you are overriding `/usr/sbin/randomscript`, move it to `/usr/sbin/randomscript.real` (maybe using diversions if you are on a Debian-based distro) and write a new `/usr/local/sbin/randomscript` something like

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/randomscript.real # Add & at the end to run it in the background
/path/to/file/file start
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Tomcat [Doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) the `startup.sh`should not be adjusted but a `setenv.sh` be created which is expected in the directory "bin" of your tomcat installation. There you can use the shell commands as usual.